# Chi-square test for image encryption

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, neyman-pearson-lemma

I have a cipher image $C$ that has intensity levels between $0-255$. I want to check this cipher image for uniformness. For this, I calculated the Chi-square 
tests. The $\chi^2=270.2112$ and i know that $\chi^2(255,0.05)=293$. I am not able to interpret the result, can somebody help

Comment: This is a good walk-through of how the chi-square test works. https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section4/prc45.htm

Comment: This seems to be a handbook problem, but if it was real then I'd ask myself: do unencrypted images pass the uniformity test? Do other encrypted ones pass it? Also, if it is a handbook exercise or homework, please use [self-study] tag.

Comment: Tim makes some very good points. Certainly some unencrypted images will pass the test because the chi-squared test takes no account of *adjacency* of values. If the image had (perhaps by design) nearly equal numbers in each intensity bin it would have a low chi-squared value. Meanwhile a meaningless, highly random image could fail it (e.g. by not having any intensities above 240 while being perfectly random uniform below it, or only using even-numbered intensities)